# Excel VBA Add Items to Dynamically Created ComboBox

Tags: excel, for-loop, collections, combobox, vba

I'm dynamically creating comboboxes in my userform and I want to add the same items to every combobox on the form.

I created a collection of the items (queried from sql statement from and Access DB). Then after I create the combobox object, I performed a `for each` statement in every item inside the collection to add to the combobox, but the comboboxes do not populate! The Controls are created, but the comboboxes are empty

I checked the collection to see if I'm even getting values. (see the line where I query the collection count) and I'm getting 20 items which is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** - I recently added code at the end of my parent For Each loop that calls to show the form. This may be why the form isn't showing properly...

```
 Private Sub setVvalues(ByVal myCol as Collection)
    Dim xSel as Object, selName as String
    Dim sItem as Variant, selectItems as Collection, x as Variant
    Dim con as New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs as New ADODB.Recordset

    ........[code that already works].........

    con.Open connectionStr   '<-- public String declared elsewhere


    Set selectItems = New Collection
    sql = "SELECT [DESCRIP] FROM tbl_setpoints_categories ORDER BY [ORD] ASC;"

    rs.Open sql, con

    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
       rs.MoveFirst
       Do While Not rs.EOF
          selectItems.Add rs!DESCRIP
          rs.MoveNext
       Loop
    Else
    End If

    rs.Close
    con.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing


    MsgBox(selectItems.Count)  '<--- produces 20 items

    'myCol is a collection (passed in this sub) of object names that will be used to produce controls
    For Each x in myCol

        selName = "sel" & x & "-" & i
        Set xSel = frm_new_setpoints.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", selName, True)
        With xSel
            .Width = 120
            .Left = 384
            .Height = 18
            .Top = 44 + (i * 30)

        End With

        For Each sItem In selectItems
            xSel.AddItem sItem
        Next sItem

     i = i + 1
   Next x

   'Show the form with new controls
   frm_new_setpoints.Show

   Set xSel = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: I just tested your code in a new userform and a customized collection. Your code works for me.

Comment: Hmm...let me add a little more code (i thought it wasn't affecting it).

Comment: Where are you running the code from?

Comment: That sub is being run from a different form. I just added the rest of my code that calls the new form to be shown. Is that why the comboboxes aren't populating?

Comment: Nope. It still works for me  :)

Comment: ...weird...I'm lost now :)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `xSel.AddItem sItem` and see if the code reaches there?

Comment: Yes it did reach there. And it reached afterwards. The Form shows, and it shows the comboboxes, but they are empty...

Comment: Change this line `selectItems.Add rs!DESCRIP` to `If len(trim(rs!DESCRIP))<>0 then selectItems.Add rs!DESCRIP` Now check what is the count of the collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. That is the right way to populate dynamically created comboboxes. I believe your recordset is filling blank items to your collection and hence you are getting blank values in the combobox.

See this example

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim col As New Collection, itm As Variant
    Dim xSel As Object

    col.Add " "
    col.Add "  "
    col.Add "   "
    col.Add " "

    Set xSel = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "Sid", True)

    With xSel
        .Width = 120
        .Left = 384
        .Height = 18
        .Top = 44

        For Each itm In col
            .AddItem itm
        Next itm
    End With

    UserForm2.Show
    Set xSel = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Now if you replace

```
    col.Add " "
    col.Add "  "
    col.Add "   "
    col.Add " "
```

by

```
    col.Add "1"
    col.Add "2"
    col.Add "3"
    col.Add "4"
```

Then you will see the values populated in the comboboxes.

[image]

**Note**:

If you change the line

```
selectItems.Add rs!DESCRIP
```

to

```
If Len(Trim(rs!DESCRIP)) <> 0 Then selectItems.Add rs!DESCRIP
```

then you will notice that `MsgBox(selectItems.Count)` will no longer give you 20.